# InfoPath - Save different views to different libraries

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have a form with two views: Ticket, with some textboxes and Ticket Document, with some textboxes and a file upload. Each view must be saved to a different document library (with the same names) and each one has its own save button. After the user have saved the first view (Ticket) I show them the other one.
Now I want to save this view (Ticket Documents) in the second list, associating the ID generated in the first list to this one.

I've tried to create different data connections to each save button, but only the first view (Ticket) get saved correctly. The second one is saved but with fields in blank.

I'm using InfoPath 2013 and targeting SharePoint 2010.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used 2013, but what about a workflow in SP 2010?  Based upon a condition you supply within your workflow, a file may be copied from location A to location B.  Allow the workflow to begin when a new item arrives in Location A. I generally use a 2 minute pause  as the next step in the workflow.  Then, add a step to delete the file in the current list/library.  Finally, Stop the workflow and log a success message.

Comment: I don't wanna copy the items. The two lists have different fields. I need to save the first item (View1) in List A, get the generated ID and then save the second item (View2) in its own List B. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Whatsoever number of views we may have in the form but internally when it gets saved to SharePoint it is treated as single xml file - so thru the data connection we cannot submit the various view data to various different library - if we set different data connection also everywhere it will be same xml file which will have all view data.

Having said these - if you are handling this thru the Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO) code you can achieve this one to one view to list library mapping.

As an alternate, assume that we are handling this thru the infopath rules(not by VSTO code), my approach would be having single master form library where all infopath form data will be saved and using SharePoint designer workflow or Nintex workflow we will pull the data from the master document library(all infopath data stored) - and send the data to other respective list/library based on the business requirement.